# Windows 10 iot core usb webcam streaming to browser

Tags: video-streaming, iot, windowsiot

Is it possible to stream video and audio from usb cam (RPi 3) to a RPi hosted web page to view on android tablet using a browser. Something like combining the Blinky server with USB Webcam samples of Windows 10 iot core? How would I get started with this, I`m totally new to RPi and programming?

Comment: RPi 3 with Windows 10 iot core can stream video from USB Webcam and can host a web server. And you can [transcode the video files from one format to another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) that will be playing in a browser. The only one thing need to solve is how to send the stream to web page and present it.

Comment: Did you ever get it working i wanted to try it with latest IoT 10